# NodeJS EC2 app - way of using configurable env variables like herokus config vars?

Tags: node.js, heroku, amazon-ec2

I am trying to migrate from heroku to AWS EC2 for my node apps. Is there an easy way to setup and manage environment variables like the settings -> config vars on heroku? I am running an EC2 instance on Amazon Linux and can't find out an easy way to manage and access env vars from code.

Comment: have you seen [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)?

Comment: in development stage Im using .env files and access with dotenv package, but in production .env files dont get commited to git from where I am deploying. So I am looking for a way like herokus gui management for node config vars on EC2.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku PaaS is known for its GUI and features but in the backend `Heroku` is running your codebase on the AWS ec2 which is controlled by Heroku Architecture.

You can try some open-source PaaS on which you can add your was instance but they need some sort of server space too. You can see [this one](https://github.com/deis/deis) independent `PaaS` software which is inspired by `Heroku`.

Comment: thank you. I am aware of the fact that heroku uses AWS servers for hosting. I was generally looking for the best approach of managing and accessing .env key value pairs with EC2 instances, not some 3rd party stuff to be implemented. Regards